# Can´t import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm learning how to program on kotlin and I´m trying to follow a book exercise (Android Programming with Kotlin for Beginners, chapter 12), however, there is a part where I need to add the following import statement:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
```

So I can import my Button and TextView instances from activity_main.xml.
But the "kotlinx" word appears on color red, therefore, all the Button and TextView instances I´m trying to use appear red as well.

Not even using Alt + Enter gives me the import option.

I'll leave a copy of the code I'm using and an image so you can appreciate the errors I have.

```kotlin
    package com.example.kotlinmeetui

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.view.View
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {
    
        // An Int property to hold a value
        private var value = 0

        override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

            // Listen for all the button clicks
            btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this)
            btnTake.setOnClickListener(this)
            txtValue.setOnClickListener(this)
            btnGrow.setOnClickListener(this)
            btnShrink.setOnClickListener(this)
            btnReset.setOnClickListener(this)
            btnHide.setOnClickListener(this)
        }
    }
```

[code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALAKD.png)

Comment: what error do you see? please send the error in text not image

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to apply the plugin `kotlin-android-extensions` in the app's `build.gradle` module like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}
```

Answer (score 6):

From kotlin 1.4.20 [synthetic view has been removed](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew1420.html#deprecation-of-synthetic-views). You can use findViewById or [ViewBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration) instead

Answer (score 0):

You should [View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding), [Data Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding) or findViewById.

Kotlin synthetic deprecated in `1.4.20` version.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew1420.html#deprecation-of-synthetic-views

Kotlin synthetic deleted in `1.8` version.

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2022/02/discontinuing-kotlin-synthetics-for-views.html